# Google Cloud Storage as volume for Kubernetes Stateful Set

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, persistent-volumes

Is it possible to mount a GCP Storage bucket into a kubernetes Pod? I am aware about other volume options such as Persistent Volume Claims backed by GCP's Standard Persistent Disks which are the Disks used in GCP's Compute Engines. However, when a Standard Persistent Disk is attached to a Compute Engine, it can not be shared with a Pod.

My use case requires being able for external applications to write on some kind of Storage and at the same time have that storage mounted into a kubernetes Pod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some PV with ReadWriteMany access mode, according to this [table](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) there are no such options in GCP out-of-box. A solution would be to provision your own NFS server for that e.g. as descirbed [here](https://medium.com/@Sushil_Kumar/readwritemany-persistent-volumes-in-google-kubernetes-engine-a0b93e203180)